# 3D Bridge text design on a 3D ring modal with react-three-fiber

Tags: three.js, 3d, blender, react-three-fiber

I was trying to add a 3D custom text on a 3D blender modal for couple of weeks, but couldn't manage to find a solution. I don't even know even it's possible in three js or not.

Here is what I wanted to achieve. On a 3D ring modal, user would be able to write their name. And I want the text to match with the design. The text design is kind of like **Bridge** text design.

And on top side of the ring the text is bending a bit.

Here are the screenshots to help you understand what I was trying.[image][image][image]

It would be a great help, if someone could help me in this. I would like to honor the assistence here as well, or I would like to hire someone who can achieve this.

I've tried Three js TextGeometry but it's not working.

Comment: Who are your users? Are they Blender compitent or laymen? If the latter I'd probably use an interface like Unity or some other game engine.

Comment: No, not Unity, this will be integrated into the website, The technology we are using is react-three-fiber, three js, react

Answer (score 0):

You can import this model to your r3f app then use box geometry inside the ring model mesh to fil the gap and after that you can add logo and all as texture